# Using Bamboo Automatic Dependencies with Gradle

Tags: gradle, bamboo

We have a (very large) number of interdependent projects we're currently building monolithically with Ant and Jenkins, and we're in the process of switching to a modular build using Gradle and Bamboo.

The Gradle projects will use the Maven plugin to build JARs and POMs for deployment to a Nexus repository, but the 'official' dependency declarations are in the `build.gradle` files and the POMs are only transient artifacts.

Is there a way to get Bamboo's Maven-based [automatic dependency management](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Setting+up+plan+build+dependencies#Settingupplanbuilddependencies-AutomaticdependencymanagementwithMaven3) to work in this scenario? There are too many projects for it to be practical to configure and maintain the dependencies manually.

Comment: I don't quite understand what that feature is doing, but it sounds like you'd have to generate adequate POMs for Bamboo to pick up at the end of the build.

Comment: "generate adequate POMs for Bamboo" is easier said than done. I'm surprised that gradle has not invested enough to meet this demand so far. Bamboo is totally useless without it for all not-single-repo jvm companies out there.

Comment: @Alex Honestly, it seems like this one's on Atlassian. I'm not at a Bamboo shop or a Gradle shop now, but if I was, I'd probably start by trying to use the `maven-publish` plugin `generatePomFileFor…` ([GenerateMavenPom](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.GenerateMavenPom.html)) task to generate a POM to a custom `destination`, wherever Bamboo expects it to be, and commit that to source control. It's hacky, but it might work.

Comment: I'm coming from the path of trying to use `generatePomFileFor..` and it lacks support for modules and parents. Nothing that can't be coded on-demand but, nevertheless, I couldn't agree more that this is Bamboo's fault in the first place.